# file modification and creation

Tags: python, datetime, file-io, time, timer

How would you scan a dir for a text file and read the text file by date modified, print it to screen having the script scan the directory every 5 seconds for a newer file creadted and prints it.
Is it possible that you can help me i'm stuck and i need this real bad and i've already got the scan dir for file and print but it does not print the files by date modidfied.

```
import os,sys
os.chdir(raw_input('dir_path: ') )    
contents=os.listdir('.') #contents of the current directory
files =[]
directory=[]
Time = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(contents))
for i in contents:
    if os.path.isfile(i) == True :
       files.append(i)
    elif os.path.isdir(i) == True :
       directory.append(i)
    #printing contents
choice = ""       
for j in files:
    while choice != "quit":
            choice = raw_input("Dou you want to print file  %s (y/n): "%j)
            if choice == 'y':
               print "**************************"
               print "Printing Files %s" %j
               print "**************************"
               fileobj = open(j,'r')
               contents = fileobj.readlines()
               for k in contents:
                     sys.stderr.write(k)
               else:
                    pass
```

what i wanted is instead of my code asking if it wants to print i need it to print the files if modified by the current time meaning if it read a file that was just placed in the directory and a new one comes in it will read the new file without prompting me.
the error it's giving me is coercing to unicode: need string or buffer, list found.

Comment: It's helpful if you show what you've done so far.

Comment: show the part of the code that fails

Comment: Time = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(contents)) this is the code that fail it gives me a coercing to unicode error.

Comment: Please don't post [exact duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333157/file-modifiaction-and-manipulation/9333257#9333257). It is very impolite to do so.

Comment: @mintgreen: post the traceback of the error you're receiving. Also, why not just use `time.sleep()`, assuming that the script is doing nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) will tell you the modification time